# What do you mean by Unique IP Address?

Tags: discussion, badges, publicity-badges, ip-address

Publicist Badge :

> [image]

The definition says that it is awarded once the question's link is accessed from 1000 unique IP addresses.

1. So the question, What is unique IP address ?

   Say for example If my company's Live IP is `111.222.XXX.XXX` and it has 10K users attached. When I share my question's link to my colleagues. Most of them visited my question ( suppose 1K users ). In this case will I get this badge ?

   I mean `111.222.1.1` & `111.222.1.2` are two different unique IP addresses or you consider it as one common IP address as they both belongs to same group of 111.222 IP Address ?
2. Or All the IP addresses has to be from different IP group ( meaning different location from all over the world ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`111.222.1.1` & `111.222.1.2` are two different, hence unique IP addresses.

If your whole company was using a shared IP address outbound, then that would be a single IP address for all of the company.

Essentially, if several people are using the same computer (or several computers behind the same proxy), the visits will be coming from one IP address and be considered as a single, unique IP address.